# express error: "TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware

Tags: node.js, express

Brand new to Node and following along with this[MEAN app tutorial](https://youtu.be/PFP0oXNNveg?t=12m19s) and encountering an error when executing 'node server' in CL in Linux (I've been using sudo to mkdir and touch all the files, and run the node server).  .

```
  >sudo node server
/home/jake/web/tasker/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458
  throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn));
  ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
at Function.use         (/home/jake/web/tasker/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/jake/web/tasker/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:220:21)
at Array.forEach (native)
at EventEmitter.use (/home/jake/web/tasker/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jake/web/tasker/server.js:23:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
```

My main server.js file:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var tasks = require('./routes/tasks');
var port = 3000; 
var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
//static folder for Angular stuff
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));
//body Parser MiddleWare
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', tasks);
app.listen(port, function(){
console.log('Server has begun');
});
```

and package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tasker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
   "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "mongojs": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Either `./routes/index.js` or `./routes/tasks.js` (or both) return an object instead of a router, a route handler function or a middleware function. In any case, look at line 23 of your _actual_ server.js to find out

Answer (score 0):

I ended up redoing the tutorial, except instead of creating the folders and files via command line, I just used right-click, and now it works. So it could've been related to sudo permissions, or I simply didn't write the wrong thing my second time doing  it. Sorry for the non-answer.